# realloc: reversed pointer array?

Tags: c, realloc

I've written a rather simple(ish) stack implementation that would automatically grow its internal array buffer if needed.

For that, I'd naturally use [realloc](http://linux.die.net/man/3/realloc) - It works, however, all array elements are ordered reverse after the realloc() call.

The code in question:

- Header: [include/pd/stack.h](http://github.com/nebukadnezzar/pdlib/blob/master/include/pd/stack.h)
- Source: [src/stack/stack.c](http://github.com/nebukadnezzar/pdlib/blob/master/src/stack/stack.c)

This example will trigger said behaviour:

```
#include "pd/strlib.h"
#include "pd/stack.h"
#include "pd/memory.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int index = 0;
    char* buffer;
    pd_stack_t* stc = pd_stack_new();
    pd_stack_push(stc, "blue");
    pd_stack_push(stc, "green");
    pd_stack_push(stc, "red");
    pd_stack_push(stc, "yellow");
    pd_stack_push(stc, "pink");
    pd_stack_push(stc, "olive");
    pd_stack_push(stc, "beige");
    pd_stack_push(stc, "gold");
    pd_stack_push(stc, "grey");
    pd_stack_push(stc, "lime");
    pd_stack_push(stc, "khaki");
    while((index++) != 500)
    {
        pd_stack_push(stc, "__random_value__");
    }
    buffer = (char*)malloc(pd_stack_size(stc));
    pd_stack_dump_tomem(stc, buffer, 1);
    fprintf(stdout, "%s", buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm really clueless about this. Help please!

Comment: line 81 looks like a bug: free(gct->ptr_stack[gct->stackcount]);

Comment: @akonsu, there are a lot of problems, check out `pd_stack_pop_index` - looks like homework.

Comment: @akonsu: can you elaborate please?


@evilclown: I'm sorry to disappoint you, but I did write this in my spare time. It's not homework.

Comment: well, gct->stackcount is the number of items in the stack. gct->ptr_stack contains the stack data. the last element in the stack is at index gct->stackcount - 1 because in C array indexes start at 0. there are many other problems such as the one that evilclown mentioned.

Comment: may i recommend a book: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language_%28book%29
it explains well why you should not write code such as if((gct->stackcount) != 0) and should write if(gct->stackcount > 0)

Comment: @akonsu: True (fixed with next commit) - Although I don't exactly see the problem with pd_stack_pop_index... after all, it's supposed to remove the data and decrement stackcount?

Comment: @akonsu: Okay. I'm more experienced with C++, where I usually wouldn't have to care much about manual memory handling, since memory is handled a little different in C++, although with the same basic Idea. I started writing this library as an personal exercise (hence why I made it public domain) - I didn't expect it to be absolutely the best thing ever, but i'm certainily always open for help. :-)

Comment: in pd_stack_pop_index when you free the item at the given index, you need to shift the tail of gct->ptr_stack to remove the empty slot. not to mention that stack by definition does not have this operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like pd_stack_dump_tomem starts its index at `stack size` and decrements to 0, appending the elements in reverse order.

Change it to start at 0 and iterate to `stack size`

(It seems `realloc` is unrelated)

Comment: @nebukadnezzar: so you wanted the stack dumped in the order items were pushed instead of the order they will be popped off the stack?

Answer (score 1):

You have some fundamental problems with the stack code, so I don't think the `realloc()` is your issue.  Here are some of the things you should look into and address:

- the top item on the stack (when it's not empty) is pointed to by `(gct->stackcount - 1)`, since in `pd_stack_push()` you store a new item in `gct->ptr_stack[gct->stackcount]` then increment `stackcount`.  However, when you're accessing the top item, you use the incorrect offset, `gct->ptr_stack[gct->stackcount]` instead of `gct->ptr_stack[gct->stackcount - 1]`.  In particular, in `pd_stack_pop()`, you free that item which will might be corrupting the heap since there's not a valid pointer in that stack location.
- in `pd_stack_push()` you call `realloc()` every time a new item is pushed on to the stack.  This won't necessarily corrupt anything or cause a defect, but it's unnecessary - especially since you always ask for the same size allocation. In other words, your `realloc()` calls should be nops except for the first one.
- `pd_stack_pop_index()` doesn't even make sense unless you only ever pop the top item (in which case `pd_stack_pop()` should be used). You free something potentially in the middle of the stack, then decrement the `stackcount`, essentially making the top item (which is not necessarily what you've freed) inaccessible.  The item in the middle of the stack that was freed will now be accessed/freed again when it's popped (assuming that `pd_stack_pop()` is fixed).

Comment: Now that you mention, I couldn't agree more. It's indeed more broken than usable. Ah well, it was fun while it lasted! :-)

Comment: @nebukadnezzar - it has bugs, but I don't think it's so broken as to be useless. It just needs fixed (as all new code does)...

Comment: I guess so. I've flagged it as experimental (again), though. I'll just have to test it further...